How can I delete entire rows in Excel using Tosca?
I do not need to delete cell contents but delete entire rows.
So I have this excel file in which some rows are completed with data, and for me to be able to use this excel file in my test case, I need to delete all but the last completed row.
Excel file
I cannot seem to find any information on this. I saw that there are table tools but I don't want to do it manually but using Tosca.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you always want the last row data, then you can use $lastContentRow.
In case you need multiple rows of data, you can use while loop to buffer these values.
Then you can create a new excel sheet using 'TBox Open Excel Workbook' standard module, with the buffered values and then delete the existing excel sheet using 'TBox Delete Excel Worksheet' standard module.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
